# PHP no highlighting in org-mode code structure

Tags: org-mode, php-mode

How I can turn on highilighting php code in org-mode structure block?

[image]

Comment: I can't find ob-php anywhere. I think it is not supported in babel org-mode.

Comment: [https://github.com/stardiviner/ob-php](https://github.com/stardiviner/ob-php) 
I just copy paste ob-php.el into my init.el so I can execute php code.
The author of ob-php wrote 'I put it in Org-mode contrib/ now.' but I couldn't find it int org-mode files. 
Any ideas how highlighting can be done? Maybe from other packages?

Comment: Maybe it's been added to a new version of `org-mode` that isn't bundled with any version of Emacs yet.

Comment: You need to add opening tag `<?php` for syntax highlighting to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current versions of [`php-mode`](https://github.com/emacs-php/php-mode/) and [`org-mode`](https://orgmode.org/elpa.html), PHP syntax highlighting in org code blocks happens by default.

The version of `org-mode` in Emacs 26.1 includes this support.  For earlier versions of Emacs you can install a newer version of org-mode from its ELPA repository.

So if you have at least Emacs 26.1 for php highlighting in org-mode you need to just install php-mode.

Comment: Your answer isn't complete. Can you add the entire solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

ob-php is now in Org mode contrib and available through the `org-plus-contrib` package in [Org ELPA](https://orgmode.org/elpa.html).

You can install this package by adding Org ELPA to your `package-archives` list in your init file:

```el
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
```

Then you can install the org-plus-contrib package by opening the package manager (`M-x` `list-packages`), locate the package (`C-s` `org-plus-contrib` `RET`), mark it for installation (`i`), and finally actually install it (`x`). (It'd be nice if the package module offered an `install-package` command but until it does, you'll have to go through this process.)

If you don't want all of contrib, then you'll have to grab ob-php directly from the Org mode Git repository ([direct link](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/contrib/lisp/ob-php.el)) and load it yourself from your init file.

Comment: It should be noted that with the latest version of Org mode, ob-php breaks due to a recursive require of `org` on line 17 of `ob-php.el`. This line should be commented out and the compiled `ob-php.elc` file removed in order to get things working again.

Comment: Going forward it appears that ob-php will be removed from the new org-contrib ELPA package after Org 9.5 is released.